# system that changes your controls randomly every 10 seconds

Tags: roblox

I am a new roblox programmer and developer and i am trying to make my first real game that is an obby but every like 10 seconds your controls changes randomly. So when you press w to walk forward, you go right instead and you can like have a gui at the top of the screen that shows how long it is until the controls changes and what the current controls are. But because i am a new developer i struggled with making a script that changes the controls.

I tried making the script:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local function RandomizeControls(player)
    local controls = {
        ["w"] = "s", ["a"] = "d", ["s"] = "w", ["d"] = "a",
        ["up"] = "down", ["down"] = "up", ["left"] = "right", ["right"] = "left",
        ["q"] = "e", ["e"] = "q", ["z"] = "x", ["x"] = "z"

    }

    local function ChangeControl(input)
        return controls[input] or input
    end

    local function OnInputBegan(input, gameProcessedEvent)
        if not gameProcessedEvent then
            local newKeyCode = ChangeControl(input.KeyCode.Name)
            UserInputService.InputBegan:Fire({ KeyCode = Enum.KeyCode[newKeyCode] })
        end
    end

    UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(OnInputBegan)

    while true do
        wait(10) 
        controls = {
            ["w"] = "s", ["a"] = "d", ["s"] = "w", ["d"] = "a",
            ["up"] = "down", ["down"] = "up", ["left"] = "right", ["right"] = "left",
            ["q"] = "e", ["e"] = "q", ["z"] = "x", ["x"] = "z"

        }
    end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    RandomizeControls(player)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your current approach does not work (yet), is because you didn't change the code of the controller module to accomodate your controls.

The best approach is to clone the PlayerModule and it's children, findable at Player > Player... > PlayerScripts at runtime, and cutting out the userinputservice event listeners that are responsible for handling the movement, then you can modify your script to require that controller module and fire the movement functions directly.

The following is a code snippet inside the Keyboard module (responsible for movement using keyboard controls). I've tweaked the original code to invert the controls, e.g. pressing A walks to the right instead of the left etc.

```lua
ContextActionService:BindActionAtPriority("moveForwardAction", handleMoveForward, false,
        self.CONTROL_ACTION_PRIORITY, Enum.PlayerActions.CharacterBackward)
    ContextActionService:BindActionAtPriority("moveBackwardAction", handleMoveBackward, false,
        self.CONTROL_ACTION_PRIORITY, Enum.PlayerActions.CharacterForward)
    ContextActionService:BindActionAtPriority("moveLeftAction", handleMoveLeft, false,
        self.CONTROL_ACTION_PRIORITY, Enum.PlayerActions.CharacterRight)
    ContextActionService:BindActionAtPriority("moveRightAction", handleMoveRight, false,
        self.CONTROL_ACTION_PRIORITY, Enum.PlayerActions.CharacterLeft)
    ContextActionService:BindActionAtPriority("jumpAction", handleJumpAction, false,
        self.CONTROL_ACTION_PRIORITY, Enum.PlayerActions.CharacterJump)
```

To make your custom module take effect, place it in StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts (See image)
[image]